# Problems with Empty Activity on Android Studio

Tags: android

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with my problem:

I am using *Android Studio*. I want to create the simplest of apps: Just a "Hello World" would be ok.

So I start by creating a new app with an *Empty Activity*  (so far I was using a "Blank Activity" but as you know, they are different.

So I create the basic code (and I find several problems -for example "cant resolve symbol AppCompatActivity- but I dont know how, it got solved...and then I have other problems..etc but...)

So, I finally get a "hello world" app, with everything ready to run. All errors corrected "by magic"- I mean really... anyway I push the Run button.(i am using genimotion by the way cause the native emulator is another problem!) and it starts to run

and I wait.... and wait.... and wait....

it never runs. I can see "gradle processes running"

So I *stop * (by clicking Run-> Stop)
the gradle processes seem to stop

and then the app finally runs succesfully and load into the genimotion emulator and I can run without problems...

So my question is: What is happening here? Why do I have to stop in order to run??

Thanks a lot for any useful help you can give me

Comment: which machine are you using and what's the specs of machine?

Comment: I am currently using a Macbook Pro. OSX El Capitan. With this machine I can run the app as indicated. (I ve tried the exact same thing in a windows 7 machine- the results are even worst. There the app can not be run)